# Supported scenario to have web part *and* assets in one SharePoint Framework package?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

### Expected behavior

Going by the tutorials I would expect to be able to make a package that contains some assets, like a list, as well as at least one web part - all in the same package.

### Observed Behavior

I can follow each tutorial to make either a list asset OR a web part, but the very moment I reference the "features" property in package-solution.json, the list is created, but the web part is no longer available to add in a new page any more. Any existing instance is also hidden/removed.

### Steps to Reproduce

Follow the tutorial for provisioning SharePoint assets (link removed due to low rep) and observe that no web part is available even though it is still defined within the package.

### Query

Has anyone succeeded in doing this or is this simply not a supported scenario?

Thanks!

### Additional information

There are no errors reported when uploading or deploying the package. The app works in "workbench" mode. I have made two packages to demonstrate:
1) version 1.0.0.20 without asset reference (the feature section of package-solution.json): https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am-J9dgZj2T5um7Nn_dkPye_OIZF
2) version 1.0.0.21 with asset reference: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am-J9dgZj2T5unAtL4O40fdzq814

Answer (score 4):

So that sounds like something is going wrong.  You certainly can provision SP objects (like lists, etc.) in your SPFX package.  When you install and deploy that package, your site should get the list created and the webpart available.  Is there any validation error in the app catalog?  You might need to add the "App Package Error Message" field to the view.

Comment: No errors reported. Additional information added to question.